# Remove underline in HyperlinkButton

Tags: xaml, hyperlink

I'm using Blend + Sketchflow Preview for Visual Studio 2012, I want to remove underlines from a HyperlinkButton.

Here is my code:

```
<HyperlinkButton x:Name="PoliciesTxt" Content="Policies" FontSize="18.667" Foreground="#FF003366" NavigateUri="http://google.com" FontWeight="Bold" CharacterSpacing="-1"/>
```

I've already tried using the `TextDecorations` attribute but it doesn't exist in this version of XAML.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You must change the default style HyperlinkButton, copy the code below on your this App.xaml file.

First you must add the following namespace in App.xaml

xmlns:vsm="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=System.Windows"

```
<Application.Resources>

        <Style x:Key="HyperlinkButtonStyle" x:Name="HyperlinkButtonStyle" TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF73A9D8" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,0,2,0"/>
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
                        <Grid Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <vsm:VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="UnderlineTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Duration="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </vsm:VisualState>
                                    <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="UnderlineTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Duration="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </vsm:VisualState>
                                    <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledOverlay" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Duration="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </vsm:VisualState>
                                </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                                <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                    <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </vsm:VisualState>
                                    <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                            </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <TextBlock
                          x:Name="UnderlineTextBlock"
                          Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                          TextDecorations="Underline"
                          Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                            <TextBlock Canvas.ZIndex="1"
                          x:Name="DisabledOverlay"
                          Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                          Foreground="#FFAAAAAA"
                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                          Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                            <ContentPresenter 
                          x:Name="contentPresenter"
                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="false" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

    </Application.Resources>
```

And you also have to apply the style to HyperlinkButton

```
<HyperlinkButton X:Name="Link" Content="Hola" Style="{StaticResource HyperlinkButtonStyle}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following Resrouce to your page (in my case I have just added it to the App.xaml page)

```
<!--Application Resources-->
<Application.Resources>
<Style x:Key="HyperlinkButtonStyle" TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
<Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
<Setter.Value>
<ControlTemplate TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
<Border Background="Transparent">
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
<VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
<VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
<VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
<Storyboard>
<DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="TextElement" 
Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.5" />
</Storyboard>
</VisualState>
<VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
<Storyboard>
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextElement" 
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
<DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" />
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
</VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
<Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="{StaticResource
PhoneHorizontalMargin}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" >
<TextBlock x:Name="TextElement" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="
{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding 
VerticalContentAlignment}" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextDecorations="none"/>
</Border>
</Border>
</ControlTemplate>
</Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Now all you need to do is drop a HyperlinkButton control onto the page and set the style as follows:

```
<HyperlinkButton Style="HyperlinkButtonStyle" />
```